# "Connection was lost error" to publish command to mosquitto broker running on ec2 instance of aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created EC2 instance in aws server and status is also showing fine, in which installed mosquitto broker and also configured security group with port 1883.

I was able to publish commands to the broker but suddenly when I try to publish commands to the broker with elastic ip address, I am getting connection was lost error from past 3 days.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have checked that mosquitto is still running on the machine, and that AWS hasn't restarted/moved the instance?

Comment: mosquito is still running because I can publish the commands with other elastic ip associated with same instance and other instance,but not with current one

Comment: and also I restarted the instance,still no use

Comment: OK, so this is most likely a AWS issue, not a mosquitto problem